# Controlling volume state of multiple audio sliders

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This creates sliders that control the volume of each individual audio:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

function NoiseSlider({ noiseSrc }) {
  const [volume, setVolume] = useState(0.5);
  const audioRef = useRef(new Audio(noiseSrc));

  useEffect(() => {
    const audio = audioRef.current;
    audio.volume = volume;
    audio.loop = true;
    audio.play();

    return () => audio.pause();
  }, [volume]);

  return (
    <input
      type="range"
      min="0"
      max="1"
      step="0.01"
      value={volume}
      onChange={(e) => setVolume(parseFloat(e.target.value))}
    />
  );
}

export function App() {
  return (
    <div className="slider-container">
      <NoiseSlider noiseSrc="https://onlinetestcase.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/100-KB-MP3.mp3" />
      <NoiseSlider noiseSrc="https://onlinetestcase.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/500-KB-MP3.mp3" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

How to affect the `volume` state of all `NoiseSlider`s at once? For example, resetting all of them to 0.5 with a single button?

Live code at [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-2ydobm?file=src%2FApp.tsx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by the famous *[Lifting the state up](https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components)* principle. You can simply lift the state up to a common ancestor component, and pass down the volume state and a function to set the volume for all sliders as props.

Now, there can be some improvements to the code but the idea for making it work will remain the same as mentioned above.

1. You can extract the noise sources and initial volumes into a separate collection and then use a more efficient way to update the state.

   ```js
   const noiseSources = [
     { id: 1, src: 'https://onlinetestcase.com/wp- 
      content/uploads/2023/06/100-KB-MP3.mp3', initialVolume: 0.5 },
     { id: 2, src: 'https://onlinetestcase.com/wp- 
      content/uploads/2023/06/500-KB-MP3.mp3', initialVolume: 0.5 },
     // Add more sources here as per requirement.
   ];
   ```
2. The `initialVolumes` object is created using the reduce function to store the initial volume for each slider based on its `id`(which is kept unique). This makes it easier to reset the volumes later.

   ```js
      const initialVolumes = noiseSources.reduce((acc, { id, initialVolume 
      }) => {
         acc[id] = initialVolume;
         return acc;
      }, {});
   ```

The final code would look like:

```js
function NoiseSlider({ noiseSrc, volume, onVolumeChange }) {
  // ...Rest of code

  useEffect(() => {
    const audio = audioRef.current;
    audio.volume = volume;
    audio.loop = true;
    audio.play();

    return () => audio.pause();
  }, [volume]);

  // ...Rest of code
}

const noiseSources = [
  {
    id: 1,
    src: 'https://onlinetestcase.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/100-KB-MP3.mp3',
    initialVolume: 0.5,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    src: 'https://onlinetestcase.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/500-KB-MP3.mp3',
    initialVolume: 0.5,
  },
  // Add more sources here if required
];

const initialVolumes = noiseSources.reduce((acc, { id, initialVolume }) => {
  acc[id] = initialVolume;
  return acc;
}, {});

export function App() {
  const [volume, setVolume] = useState(initialVolumes);

  const handleVolumeChange = (id, newVolume) => {
    setVolume((prevVolume) => ({ ...prevVolume, [id]: newVolume }));
  };

  const resetVolume = () => {
    setVolume(initialVolumes);
  };

  return (
    <div className="slider-container">
      {noiseSources.map(({ id, src }) => (
        <NoiseSlider
          key={id}
          noiseSrc={src}
          volume={volume[id]}
          onVolumeChange={(newVolume) => handleVolumeChange(id, newVolume)}
        />
      ))}
      <button onClick={resetVolume}>Reset volume</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

***[CODE DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-dmlaum?file=src%2FApp.tsx)***

Comment: But now that both `NoiseSlider`s are using the same `volume` state, they increase and decrease together, instead of individually.

Comment: I see. So the only solution is to move `volume` up a component then use `index` to match it with its corresponding `NoiseSlider`. Okay, update the answer.

Comment: @wyc, I have updated the answer. Please take a look once.

Answer (score 1):

"NoiseSlider" is a custom element so it's anyone's guess how it was constructed.

But had it been the standard audio player then you could've just done this to set all volume levels at once...

```
var V=document.querySelectorAll('audio'); // or video

for(var i=0; i<V.length; i++){

 V[i].volume = 0.5;

}
```

I hope this helps.

You may want to give the above loop a try with...

```
var V=document.querySelectorAll('NoiseSlider');
```

But I wouldn't hold my breath for this... :)